# EditText array FocusChange

Tags: java, android, android-view

I have 80 EditText fields (cube[i]) and want to read what is in inside the text fields when the text field loses focus.

I can detect when any of the EditTexts (cube) loses focus but I cannot detect exactly which one, Im trying to find which cube is focused on.

the line "EditText cube = (EditText) v.getClass();" is giving me an error

Maybe I can use the View v?

```
            for (int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++) {

        cube[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    EditText cube = (EditText) v.getClass();
                    String s = cube.getText().toString();
                    //cubecolor();

                }
            }
        });

    }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: just use EditText cube = (EditText) v;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while creating set some tag to the editText like this (pseudo code)

```
EditText edit = new EditText(context);
edit.setTag(Integer.valueOf(i)); // i is within the for loop;
```

Now during the onFocus get the tag

```
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                EditText cube = (EditText) v;
                Integer tag = (Integer)cube.getTag();
                //code to sort out which cube based on tag
                String s = cube.getText().toString();
                //cubecolor();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, Thanks Dante.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++) {
        cube[i].setTag(Integer.valueOf(i)); // give cubes tags
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < cube.length; i++) {

        cube[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {

                    Integer tag = (Integer) v.getTag();
                    String s = cube[tag].getText().toString();
                                            Log(TAG, " Content" + s);
                    revert_cubecolor(tag);

                }
            }
        });

    }
```